# Disable burger menu while the user is inside another menu option

Tags: javascript, css

I just need to disable my burger menu while the user is inside another menu option. Unfortunately nothing can disable it as the menu is always active.

PS: the functions disableLink() and ableLink() dont work, everything else works fine.

---

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {

    document.querySelector('.nav-wrapper').classList.toggle('change');

    var x = document.getElementById("top-nav-id");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }

    document.querySelector('#home-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {

      document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "block";

      disableLink();
    });

    document.querySelector('#close-window').addEventListener('click', () => {

      document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "none";

      ableLink();
    });
});

function disableLink() {
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').removeAttribute('href');    
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').style.textDecoration = 'none';
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').style.cursor = 'default';
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').style.visibility = hidden;
  document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').style['pointer-events'] = 'none';

  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').removeAttribute('href');    
  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').style.textDecoration = 'none';
  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').style.cursor = 'default';
  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').style.visibility = hidden;
  document.getElementById('hamburger-menu').style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
}

function ableLink() {
  document.getElementById('change').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('change').addAttribute('href');    
  document.getElementById('change').style.textDecoration = 'solid'
  document.getElementById('change').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61644858/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] please

Comment: Also please use CSS and `document.getElementById('nav-wrapper').classList.toggle("disabledClass",someBooleanTest)`

Answer (score 0):

In the click event listener, I can see the 'nav-wrapper', 'hamburger-menu' and 'change' are classes not ids. So rather than `document.getElementById` you should use the selector you'd used above, `document.querySelector`.

On a side-note, read up on [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) so you can be more specific when selecting elements using class names. Otherwise use an id if targeting a specific element.